# Are any of the Google's App Engine sample apps written in Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, sample

I was looking at this repository of sample apps for Google App Engine:

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/

The strange thing is they all seem to be in Python.

Are there any Java sample apps for GAE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some well documented code samples [here](http://code.google.com/p/pgae-examples/source/browse/1e/). They accompany a book but feel useful as a stand alone, too. You can find an overview in the [README_java.txt](http://code.google.com/p/pgae-examples/source/browse/1e/README_java.txt) .

**Update**

These are [sources of another book](http://www.manning.com/gift/GAESource.zip).

Answer (score 3):

This is nice example for beginners.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html

Answer (score 2):

All the examples in that repository are currently Python only. Here's an example app from I/O 2009 that's written in Java: [Plane-crazy](http://code.google.com/p/plane-crazy-demo/).